# Print_r displaying two different post->ID if placed in sidebar or single.php

Tags: wordpress, post, tags

My website is displaying, if print_r, two different ID for the same post.
If i ask:

```
<?php 
 echo $post->ID;?>
</div>
```

in the single.php it gives me a number. If i do the same thing in the sidebar it gives me a completely different one.

This is what I get with the print_r on the single.php

```
stdClass Object ( [ID] => 59 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2012-01-01 20:29:18 
[post_date_gmt] => 2012-01-01 20:29:18 [post_content] => È universalmente
riconosciuto (...) [post_title] => fdsfdsfs [show_in_menu] => 1 [link_link] => 1
[no_follow_link] => 0 [alt_link_text] => [custom_link_class] => [redirect_url] =>
[target_blank] => 0 [alt_title_attribute] => [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish
[comment_status] => closed [ping_status] => closed [post_password] =>
[post_name] => fdsfdsfs [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2012-01-07 19:53:44
[post_modified_gmt] => 2012-01-07 19:53:44 [post_content_filtered] =>
[post_parent] => 0 [guid] => http://www.museidibra.it/prova/?p=59 [menu_order] => 0
[post_type] => post [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0
[ancestors] => Array ( ) [filter] => raw )
```

While this is what I get from the sidebar:

```
stdClass Object ( [ID] => 93 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2012-01-02 08:39:29
[post_date_gmt] => 2012-01-02 08:39:29 [post_content] => prova 3 (...)
[post_title] => prova 3 [show_in_menu] => 1 [link_link] => 1 [no_follow_link] => 0
[alt_link_text] => [custom_link_class] => [redirect_url] => [target_blank] => 0
[alt_title_attribute] => [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish
[comment_status] => closed [ping_status] => closed [post_password] =>
[post_name] => prova-3 [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2012-01-07 13:06:15
[post_modified_gmt] => 2012-01-07 13:06:15 [post_content_filtered] =>
[post_parent] => 0 [guid] => http://www.museidibra.it/prova/?p=93 [menu_order] => 0
[post_type] => post [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw )
```

It is basically 2 different posts.

**NOTE:** this thing happens only in post that i tagged. I f i don't tag the post, the resulting IDs will be the same.

Help please, this thing is freaking me out.

Thanks

Comment: I have a single.php that calls the sidebar-ottava.php. I would love to have a button on the sidebar that could display all the post of the category of the current post. I noticed the problem because the button i created was linking to a different category. So, i used the echo->id to check if the ID of the post was the same: the sidebar thinks I am somewhere else. If I put echo->id in the single.php and in the sidebar, it displays two different id. I really can't be more specific, it is just crazy. Here is a page [link](http://www.museidibra.it/prova/prova-tag-img-arte/), please help

Comment: one number is after the post (91), the other one is on the upper-right side (333). It must have something to do with the tag, because it only happen if I tag the post

Comment: do a print_r($post) from the 2 files, copy and paste in your question

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally I got the problem solved! I need a `wp_reset_query()` because I was loading other posts based on the tag at the bottom of the page and the ID of the post in the sidebar was the last post loaded. After the reset, it started showing the right ID.